# PHP MongoDB driver and Shared web hosting

Tags: php, mongodb, shared-hosting, php-mongodb

i just deployed my php/mogodb website (php part in a shared web hosting, and mongodb in mongohq)

my probleme is that the instaled php in the shared web host don't contains any mongo driver

How to solve this?

Comment: You need to contact your hoster for solutions. Ask them to install the driver/extension for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally speaking, shared hosting providers are not equipped for PHP/MongoDB deployments. Getting MongoDB working with PHP requires a compilation and some config changes which you generally cannot do on shared hosts.

You basically have two options:

1. Contact your provider and ask them to perform the installation for you. This may or may not happen for you, but it's probably worth a call.
2. Get a small "virtual machine" that you can configure. There are lots of hosts that will give you 512MB computer with full access (Linode, Joyent, Rackspace, AWS, etc).

Given that you're using MongoHQ for your MongoDB hosting, I would check which Data Center they're using for hosting. Getting a VM in the same DC will definitely help the speed of your app.